# TypeError: $ is not a function while trying to signup

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an error in code that is saying that "$ is not a function" That appears on line 53.
Signup.componentDidMount
C:/projekti/studying/src/auth/signup.js:53

```
  50 |         }
  51 |     });
  52 | 
> 53 |     $('#avatar_image').hide();
     | ^  54 | }
  55 | 
  56 | componentWillMount() {
```

With what do i need to replace it? Or how to correct it? And why is it recognising it as an error?

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your project?

Comment: i had, i even defined var $ = require("jquery")(window);

Comment: Ensure jQuery is actually loaded when you're running that code.